Error while installing ruby on rails on windows 11
I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails, but when I run the command "gem install rails", PowerShell throws this error:
C:\Users\milos>gem install rails
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/milos/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
chyba: selhala příprava transakce (nelze zamknout databázi)
chyba: nelze uzamknout databázi: Permission denied
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/milos/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/psych-5.1.2/ext/psych
C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pkg-config for yaml-0.1... not found
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --without-opt-include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --without-opt-lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --without-libyaml-include
        --with-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib
        --without-libyaml-lib



see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Users/milos/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/psych-5.1.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/milos/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/psych-5.1.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/milos/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/psych-5.1.2/gem_make.out


The mkmf.log file shows the following message:
pkg_config: checking for pkg-config for yaml-0.1... -------------------- not found
I've tried various methods to download yaml, but none of them seem to work. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance for your response.

Start with the first error. chyba: nelze uzamknout databázi: Permission denied or in English error: unable to lock database: Permission denied. That probably means your package manager's (pacman?) database. That probably means something else was using it, another instance of pacman running? See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#%22Failed_to_init_transaction_(unable_to_lock_database)%22_error

Related conversation.

Basically it is not good idea to develop Ruby projects a little more complex than hello-world on Windows (WSL is ok), you will always have some problems with C-libraries

@mechnicov the biggest problem with developing on Windows is that you're unlikely to actually be deploying to a windows server and you don't want to find out about the inconsistencies between Windows and whatever linux distro the the deployment server is running after you deploy.

@max While I generally agree, this is an issue with their package manager. Slow down.

@max there is indeed a vicious circle. Unsupported parts of gems do not allow Windows servers to deploy without issues, and if you do not need Windows servers, then there is no point in supporting gems for Windows either. Well, it's more philosophical:)

As pointed out by others here, development of ruby on native windows is inherently error prone, especially when dealing with the newest releases of ruby. I have developed ruby applications in a Windows environment for the better part of 12 years now, starting in just windows (as you are now), then moving to an Ubuntu VM, and now operating through WSL. WSL has been the cleanest experience as it allows you to develop within the Windows OS you are accustom to while installing and running everything in a linux environment. It makes everything simpler and I would highly recommend the transition.

i resolved it, here are the steps to remedy it
Open your MSYS2 terminal part, then run:
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

run terminal as admin if it fails
it will install 13 of packages available
then retry
gem install rails

